# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'You need to spend more ETH!'

Tags: javascript, deployment, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

At the unit testing section on solidity course Lesson7 around 11：23

[https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=41004。](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=41004%E3%80%82)
Failed the test "updated the amount funded data structure".
Seems like sendValue failed
but I declared the sendValue for 1 Ether and pass the args of sendvalue.

Error Information

```
FundMe
fund
updated the amount funded data structure:
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'You need to spend more ETH!'
at FundMe.fund (contracts/FundMe.sol:40)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
```

test script - fundme.test.js

```
const sendValue = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")

describe("fund", async function () {
    it("Fails if you don't send enough ETH", async function () {
        await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        )
    })

    it("updated the amount funded data structure", async function () {
        // 执行fund，获取funder的地址=>金额映射，和fund的金额做对比
        await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
        const response = await fundMe.addressToAmountFunded(deployer)
        assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString())
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the "async" word from:

```
describe("fund", async function () {
```